# How to print an exact element (given column and row) of a csv file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm not sure how to print an exact element (like column 5, row 3) of a csv file in PHP. I have a CSV file with 3 columns: ID, cost, location. I need to search for the ID, which I can do and I can even return what row number it is. But then how can I print off that row's column 3? The code below prints the line number where $interior can be found.

```
$lines = file('database.csv');
$line_number = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {
   $line_number = (strpos($line, $interior) !== FALSE);
}
if($line_number){
$search = $interior;
$line_number = false;
if ($handle = fopen("database.csv", "r")) {
   $count = 0;
   while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== FALSE and !$line_number) {
  $count++;
  $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? $count : $line_number;
   }
  fclose($handle);
}
echo $line_number;
```

Comment: [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is your friend.

Comment: @AndyE if any of the answers is correct or helpful you should upvote and/or mark the answer as correct with the "V" button next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
  $lines = file('database.csv');
```

Gave you the lines in an array then:

```
  $line = explode(",", $lines[2]);
```

Will give you an array of each elemet of row 3 (note the two (+1) in the lines variable).

So...

```
  Echo $line[4];
```

Will be the third row and fifth column of database.csv

Comment: `$lines` will be 0-indexed, hence your code checks the 4th line. Also: If any of the columns can contain a comma your `explode` is screwed. I suggest using [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) instead of explode. It's basically the same thing except it allows you to set certain parameters (enclosing characters, field separators etc).

Comment: Correct... it's still morning.

Comment: @ccKep in response to yor edit: if the elements in a CSV contain the same char as the delimiter, then the problem is the CSV itself. You never use the delimiter in the elements.

Comment: `"foo,bar","foo","bar"` is valid csv - yet your explode would break.

Comment: Well your delimiter is not comma in your example, I would say the delimiter is '","' and not only ','

Comment: It's not. My fields are enclosed in `"`, which is exactly why `str_getcsv` let's you specify such things. Your explode would give `"foo,bar`, `bar"` as my first/last element respectively.

Comment: @ccKep are you a doomsday prepper too? I mean seriously? We have not even seen how his database is built, and you are making a none excisting issues as a big problem. If there was anything extra ordinary in his CSV, meaning anything else than a comma between the values it is his fault for not giving us example data.

Comment: No need to get aggressive, I'm just saying there's a reason `str_getcsv` exists. It would've been a minor change to your code to make it fool-proof. Other users might come along while searching for a similar problem / other answers could link to this (eg. as duplicates). `But seriously, who cares?` is not what this is about....

Comment: Fair enough. But In my opinion, if someone has this low knowledge of strings and arrays (no pun intended Andy), I think it's better to get a code you can gasp, use and learn from than a code that does the job in one line and you have no clue of why. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Since this question lacks a complete (non-breaking) answer:

You can simply use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) on each line of your csv and store the results in an array:

```
$lines = file('database.csv');
$data = array();
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    // if your CSV uses a different delimiter or you enclose your fields with a different character than " alter the following line according to the php docs of str_getcsv
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

// get row 3, column 5:
echo $data[2][4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of all comma(as it is CSV file) then on the basis of  `strpos($line, $search)` this function's return you can decide the column.But if any of your column will contain comma, this logic will fail.
For that case, search the positions of `",` (assuming your column will quoted by double quote).
You can put it inside your while loop:

```
$searchStr = "CA" ;
$mystr = "5,50.00,CA";
$myArr = explode(",",$mystr);
foreach($myArr as $k=>$v)
{    
    if($v == $searchStr)
        echo "Column :". $k;
}
```

Comment: Ok I'm still a little confused. If I KNOW I want to print column 2, row 3 of my csv file, how could I do that?

Comment: you can do it 2 way..Either explode the string on the basis of "comma"& then search your "search" pattern.when you have matched you can show it. Another way is when your strpos() return the position , you will check is this position is greater than of which comma's position.